# Cross-compile QT application on TX1

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux

I want to cross-compile my QT application on x64 PC (Ubuntu 14.04),
and deploy the it on Jetson TX1 (ARMv8, Ubuntu 16.04).

I've found some tutorial is about how to install QT creator on TX1,
but I want to develop the application on PC and port it to TX1 instead of
develop the application on TX1 directly.

Is there any tutorial about this?
Thanks.

Comment: Is it reasonable to make your application work on both platforms and only compile _on_ the ARM platform when you're ready to deploy?  I run my Qt app on linux, windows, and android, but I do most of my development and testing on linux.

Comment: I want to develop on Ubuntu and deploying it on ARM, so I need to build my application on both platform. I'm developing the application on Ubuntu now, so I need to cross-compile my application in order to run on ARM platform.